# Can you heal your posse?

Tags: dead-rising-3

During the game, you can complete side missions and build up your posse.  After a short time though, they die due to too many zombies.

Is there any way to heal them?  If so, how?

I have told them to scavange before, but they only pick up the nearest item and start hitting zombies over the head with whatever they find.

Answer (score 1):

You can heal your posse by picking up food or drink items and "giving" them to your posse members, like you would any weapons.

Funnily enough, if you give them the "Randomizer" mixed juice, they will actually throw up too!

Hope that helps and Merry Christmas!